# Socket performance

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, network-programming

I just wondered about how Instant Messengers and Online Games can accept and deliver messages so fast. (Network programming with sockets)

I read about that this is done with **nonblocking sockets**.
I tried **blocking sockets** with pthreads (each client gets its own thread) and **nonblocking sockets** with `kqueue`.Then I profiled both servers with a program which made 99 connections (each connection in one thread) and then writes some garbage to it (with a sleep of 1 second). When all threads are set up, I measured in the main thread how long it took to get a connection from the server (with wall clock time) (while "99 users" are writing to it).

`threads (avg): 0.000350 // only small difference to kqueue
kqueue (avg):   0.000300 // and this is not even stable (client side)`

The problem is, while testing with *kqueue* I got multiple times a `SIGPIPE` error (client-side). (With a little timeout `usleep(50)` this error was fixed). I think this is **really** bad because a server should be capable to handle thousands of connections. (Or is it my fault on the client side?) The crazy thing about this is the infamous pthread approach did just fine (with and without timeout).

So my question is: how can you build a **stable** socket server in `C` which can handle thousands of clients "asynchronously"? I only see the threads approach as a good thing, but this is considered bad practice.

Greetings

EDIT:

My test code:

```c
double get_wall_time(){
    struct timeval time;
    if (gettimeofday(&time,NULL)){
        //  Handle error
        return 0;
    }
    return (double)time.tv_sec + (double)time.tv_usec * .000001;
}

#define NTHREADS    100

volatile unsigned n_threads = 0;
volatile unsigned n_writes  = 0;

pthread_mutex_t main_ready;
pthread_mutex_t stop_mtx;
volatile bool running = true;

void stop(void)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&stop_mtx);
    running = false;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&stop_mtx);
}

bool shouldRun(void)
{
    bool copy;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&stop_mtx);
    copy = running;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&stop_mtx);

    return copy;
}

#define TARGET_HOST "localhost"
#define TARGET_PORT "1336"

void *thread(void *args)
{
    char tmp = 0x01;

    if (__sync_add_and_fetch(&n_threads, 1) == NTHREADS) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&main_ready);

        fprintf(stderr, "All %u Threads are ready...\n", (unsigned)n_threads);
    }

    int fd = socket(res->ai_family, SOCK_STREAM, res->ai_protocol);

    if (connect(fd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) != 0) {
        socket_close(fd);

        fd = -1;
    }

    if (fd <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket_create failed\n");
    }

    if (write(fd, &tmp, 1) <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pre-write failed\n");
    }

    do {
        /* Write some garbage */
        if (write(fd, &tmp, 1) <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "in-write failed\n");

            break;
        }

        __sync_add_and_fetch(&n_writes, 1);

        /* Wait some time */
        usleep(500);
    } while (shouldRun());

    socket_close(fd);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];

    pthread_mutex_init(&main_ready, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&main_ready);
    pthread_mutex_init(&stop_mtx, NULL);

    bzero((char *)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    hint.ai_socktype    = SOCK_STREAM;
    hint.ai_family      = AF_INET;

    if (getaddrinfo(TARGET_HOST, TARGET_PORT, &hint, &res) != 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread, NULL);
    }

    /* wait for all threads to be set up */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&main_ready);

    fprintf(stderr, "Main thread is ready...\n");

    {
        double start, end;
        int fd;

        start = get_wall_time();

        fd = socket(res->ai_family, SOCK_STREAM, res->ai_protocol);

        if (connect(fd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) != 0) {
            socket_close(fd);

            fd = -1;
        }

        end = get_wall_time();

        if (fd > 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Took %f ms\n", (end - start) * 1000);

            socket_close(fd);
        }
    }

    /* Stop all running threads */
    stop();
    /* Waiting for termination */
    for (int i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Performed %u successfull writes\n", (unsigned)n_writes);

    /* Lol.. */
    freeaddrinfo(res);

    return 0;
}
```

`SIGPIPE` comes when I try to connect to the `kqueue` server (after 10 connections are made, the server is "stuck"?). And when too many users are writing stuff, the server cannot open a new connection. (`kqueue` server code from http://eradman.com/posts/kqueue-tcp.html)

Comment: Is your question really, "how do I write high-performance TCP server code?"

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes. Indeed.

Comment: read up on select. Read the classic books on unix network programming

Answer (score 1):

`SIGPIPE` means you're trying to write to a socket (or pipe) where the other end has already been closed (so noone will be able to read it).  If you don't care about that, you can ignore `SIGPIPE` signals (call `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)`) and the signals won't be a problem.  Of course the `write` (or `send`) calls on the sockets will still be failing (with `EPIPE`), so you need to make you code robust enough to deal with that.

The reason that `SIGPIPE` normally kills the process is that its too easy to write programs that ignore errors on `write`/`send` calls and run amok using up 100% of CPU time otherwise.  As long as you carefully always check for errors and deal with them, you can safely ignore `SIGPIPE`s

Answer (score 0):

> Or is it my fault?

It was your fault. TCP works. Most probably you didn't read all the data that was sent.

> And when too many users are writing stuff, the server cannot open a new connection

Servers don't open connections. Clients open connections. Servers *accept* connections. If your server stops doing that, there something wrong with your accept loop. It should only do two things: accept a connection, and start a thread.

Comment: I meant what I said. No more, no less. This error is usually caused by writing to a connection that had already been closed by the other end. In other words, an application protocol error.